Enumerar elementos de un array (contador, valor), similar al enumerate de Python
Esta es una pregunta auto-contestada
¿Existe alguna instrucción para iterar un array en el que se pueda enumerar sus elementos? Pseudo-código: [(0,v1), (1,v2), ..., (++c,vn)] El contador debe empezar en cero y ser consecutivo, similar al enumerate de Python.
En Python:
var = ['pera', 'manzana', 'tomate']
for k, v in enumerate(var):
    print(k, v)

0 pera
1 manzana
2 tomate

Una simulación de la instrucción puede ser:
<?php
$arr = ['pera', 'manzana', 'tomate'];
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    echo "$k $v" . PHP_EOL;
}

// O también de otra forma:
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    echo "$i $arr[$i]" . PHP_EOL;
}


En cualquier caso la salida es exactamente la deseada:
0 pera
1 manzana
2 tomate

Sin embargo, estas aproximaciones no son convenientes ¿por qué?

La principal razón por la cual no existe un "enumerate" en PHP es porque los arrays de PHP NO son iguales a las listas o tuplas de Python.
El array de PHP es un arreglo indexado llave=>valor y su estructura correspondiente en Python sería un diccionario.
Debido a que un array es un arreglo indexado, PHP no puede predecir que tipo de índices tendrá un arreglo, si estos son consecutivos o no, y sobre todo, si esos índices son importantes para el usuario.

PHP siempre creará elementos en un array como llave=>valor, independiente si se especifican o no las llaves.
Si la llave no es especificada, PHP la creará automáticamente y será el mayor entero usado como llave + 1.
Si se elimina un elemento, PHP no reindexa el array, el espacio permanecerá.

$arr = [-5=>'pera', -3=>'manzana', 'tomate'];
var_export($arr);
// [-5=>'pera', -3=>'manzana', -2=>'tomate']

$arr = ['pera', 'manzana', 'tomate'];
unset($arr[1]); // Eliminar un elemento
var_export($arr);
// [0=>'pera', 2=>'tomate']

Con este par de ejemplos se puede ver que el foreach, tal como se plantea en la pregunta, no funcionará porque nada garantiza que los índices empezarán en cero y mucho menos que serán consecutivos. Por supuesto, es una muy mala idea tratar de hacer esto con un for tradicional:
$arr = ['pera', 'manzana', 'tomate'];
unset($arr[1]); // <- Eliminar un elemento

for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    echo "$i $arr[$i]".PHP_EOL;
}

0 pera
Warning: Undefined array key 1

Solución
Una forma "segura" de crear un comportamiento similar a "enumerate" en PHP, es omitiendo los índices, o llaves originales, y crear otro array reinidexado a partir de los valores. La instrucción para eso es array_values:
$arr = ['pera', 12=>'manzana', 'index03'=>'tomate'];
foreach(array_values($arr) as $k=>$v) {
    echo "$k $v".PHP_EOL;
}

0 pera
1 manzana
2 tomate


Extra
La solución con array_values es suficiente para obtener el comportamiento deseado, pero para los que se quieren complicar la vida y desean construir un objeto tipo [[c1, v1], [c2, v2], ...] similar a enumerate(), se pueden crear un generador como:
function enumerate($array) {
    foreach(array_values($array) as $k=>$v) {
        yield [$k, $v];
    }
}

$arr = ['pera', 'manzana', 'tomate'];

$generator = enumerate($arr);
var_export(iterator_to_array($generator));
// [[0, 'pera'], [1, 'manzana'], [2, 'tomate']]

Entonces, para iterar el objeto:
foreach(enumerate($arr) as list($k, $v)) {
    echo "$k $v".PHP_EOL;
}

0 pera
1 manzana
2 tomate


Pero esto no es similar al enumerate de Phyton, como se lee en el título de la pregunta. Si lees la documentación se observa que enumerate() acepta un segundo parámetro opcional que sería el inicio de los índices. Es decir, enumerate() no te da siempre unos datos empezando por el índice 0 como pretende el código de la respuesta. La doc dice que: returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

Revisa esta respuesta la cual traduce a enumerate() desde el código fuente.

Claro @A.Cedano es una duda más que todo para no tan expertos en el lenguaje y que no se les ocurra hacer este tipo de contador con un ciclo estándar. La respuesta, mas que buscar un código exacto de traducción de la función, es para explicar por qué no se debe hacer lo que se expone en la pregunta. Y bueno, lo de los contadores iniciales sería bastante sencillo de implementar en la versión con el generador. Y si das una mejor respuesta, te la marco ;)
